# SLD space in TTF url fails

Tags: geoserver, sld, rest

Use geoserver rest interface to create a style,param like below
url:http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/qgisImport/styles
Content-Type:application/vnd.ogc.se+xml;charset=UTF-8
body:
...

```
<se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ttf://ESRI Default Marker"/>
```

...
with a result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for href: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 6: ttf://ESRI Default Marker
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using your TTF reference in the context of a `Mark` not an external graphic (this is to make sure that GeoServer doesn't think it is a URL). So you need something like (see the [documentation for more information](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#bulk-ttf-marks)):

```
 <PointSymbolizer>
     <Graphic>
       <Mark>
         <WellKnownName>ttf://Webdings#0x0064</WellKnownName>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#AAAAAA</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Stroke/>
       </Mark>
     <Size>16</Size>
   </Graphic>
 </PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: I change my sld like this
<se:Mark>
 <se:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Default Marker</se:WellKnownName>
        <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
</se:Mark>
the previous error doesn't appear， but the sld doesn't work

Comment: I got it,Thank you very much~